# How to use functions from BluetoothAPIs.h in C#?

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I am going to make a project using this language - really simple Bluetooth WPF app. I am familiar with BluetoothAPIs.h functions like BluetoothFindFirstRadio or BluetoothGetDeviceInfo. I would like to use them in my program but I don't know how to make the compiler recognize them. Should I use some namespace, include something or what? Sorry for silly question, I am kind of a beginner here.

Comment: I'd recommend reading an article on the differences between C# and C++.  .h files are C/C++ and just don't mean anything for C#.

Comment: @theGleep Thanks, I know the difference and I know that header files can't be used in C#. That's why I asked my questions - I just wanted to know if this API's functions can be somehow used in C# as in C++.

Comment: Sorry - it wasn't obvious in your question.  Who provides the bluetooth API you're using?

Comment: I don't get your question. Maybe I'm still not clear enough (excuse me then). I just want to use this stuff:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362927(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ah - ok.  The built-in APIs.  Here's one way to do it: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-win32-api-in-net/

Comment: I guess I'm really bad at asking questions, sorry. :) Thanks for help! That article seems to solve my problem.

Comment: You're welcome.  Sometimes it's tough to figure out the google-fu